# How to configure which HDMI port to use in (k)ubuntu if I have a AMD hybrid configuration with a discrete video card

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video, xorg, amd-processor

I have a PC configuration that has an AMD APU processor with Radeon Graphics and a Discrete Radeon graphics card.
AMD recommends to use the HDMI/VGA/DVI port of the discrete video card for best performance on  Windows so I have connected the HDMI port to Discrete Card.
When I boot to linux ubuntu distributive (linux mint 15) I have only video output of Xorg on the motherboard HDMI. But when the system is booting I have video output on every port. So on discrete card port i get only the "_" text. So my thought is that xorg.conf is not properly configured.

So how can I configure xorg.conf  to get video output on discrete HDMI port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution

Just need to run in terminal after installation

```
sudo amdconfig --initial -f --adapter=all
```

Original wiki
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Raring_Installation_Guide